# Can't get Windbg to load symbols

Tags: windows, debugging, stack-overflow, windbg

I'll admit to being completely new to Windbg so hopefully this is a noobish question that I couldn't find the answer for on the internet.

Anyways, here is my symbol path: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

I have a small command line program that I made, so I go to File -> Open Executable

I select the .exe and give it the two arguments from that screen.  I then go to the Command window and press 'g' to run my program.  I get the following output.

```
CommandLine: C:\Users\me\devcode\folder\program\myprogram.exe input1 outputdir
Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 01320000 01367000   image01320000
ModLoad: 779b0000 77b30000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 76e30000 76f40000   C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 76790000 767d7000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
(19a8.1cf0): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=cb5b0000 edx=0026ddf8 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=77a50fab esp=001af830 ebp=001af85c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
77a50fab cc              int     3
0:000> g
(19a8.1cf0): Stack overflow - code c00000fd (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for image01320000
eax=008872a8 ebx=7efde000 ecx=008872a8 edx=00887e60 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=01327076 esp=000b2fe4 ebp=000b3028 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
image01320000+0x7076:
01327076 53              push    ebx
```

I am most concerned about the line that reads:

`*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for image01320000`

Where does image01320000 come from?  Shouldn't this be the name of my executable?  I do have .pdb files that were created.

Yes, my program is built in debug mode.  I'm just trying to get a stacktrace so I can find the source of the stack overflow it is reporting.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the output of `!lmi image01320000;lmvm image01320000;lm m myprog*` ?

Comment: [Verifying Symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560260(v=vs.85).aspx)